# Can a DenseFeatures layer have an input_shape defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to define an input_shape for my model. I know that when you define it for the first layer, it will be used for the rest of the layers. But when I try to give it an input_shape it just returns:

```
ValueError: ('We expected a dictionary here. Instead we got: ', <tf.Tensor 'fl_input:0' shape=(None, 32) dtype=float32>)
```

I tried packing it into a dictionary somehow, but the error remains.
How can I give my model an input_shape?

Code:

```
batch_size = 32
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, name='fl', input_shape=(batch_size,))#, input_shape=(batch_size,))

train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

# layers
# no difference between acivation functions and layers
relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)

# model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

if len(dataframe.index)<100:
    #model.add(layers.Input(shape=(batch_size,)))
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
elif 100<len(dataframe.index)<1000:
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
elif 1000<len(dataframe.index):
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='3'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In input shape of dense layer(i.e feature_layer in this code) you need to specify height, width and channels (i.e in case of grey image mention as '1' or for RGB mention as '3') along with Batch size.

The order of Input shape is ***Batch_Size, Height, width, Channels***. If we wont specify batch size then model assume ***None, Height, width, Channels***

```
batch_size = 32
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, name='fl', input_shape=(batch_size, H, W,C))

train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

# layers
# no difference between acivation functions and layers
relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)

# model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

if len(dataframe.index)<100:
    #model.add(layers.Input(shape=(batch_size,)))
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
elif 100<len(dataframe.index)<1000:
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
elif 1000<len(dataframe.index):
    model.add(feature_layer)
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='1'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='2'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=relu, name='3'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```